# AverageIFs multiple columns when meets multiple criteria in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I tried to look for answers online but I can't seem to find the answer :(
I have multiple columns to average depending on multiple criteria in 1 column.
Here's my sample data:
[image: here's my sample data]

I used this formula but it only works when averaging 1 column (score 1)

```
=AVERAGE(IF((B3:B11={"Emp 1","Emp 2","Emp 3"}),C3:C11))
```

I tried to average Score 1 to Score 5 but it doesn't work. I'm getting "#N/A"

```
=AVERAGE(IF((B3:B11={"Emp 1","Emp 2","Emp 3"}),C3:G11))
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B10,{"Emp1","Emp2","Emp3"},0)))*(C2:G10<>""),C2:G10))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: What if I have 2 sets of range? Same as the picture above, another set of range from rows 13 to 22

Comment: New question gets a new post, with relevant information.  But try two IFs inside the average.